# please help me fix this trinumber code

Tags: python

this code is supposed to output a number of trinumbers in a table when the user puts in a number.  Example:  the user puts in 4 for a and the table runs the formula running all variables 1-4 for n in the trinumber definition and outputs it to a table.  When I run it the program says it says t is not defined.

```
def TriNumber(n):
    t == ((n(n+1))/2) #trinumber formula
    return t

a = int(input("please input a number")) #user input for number of trinumbers to output
num = 1

for num in range(a):
    TriNumber(num)
    print(" n" "\t""\t""Tri Number")
    print("***""\t""\t""   *****")
    print(num, "\t""\t",(TriNumber(num)))
    num = num + 1
```

Comment: switch `t == ((n(n+1))/2)` to `t = ((n(n+1))/2)`

Answer (score 1):

Your first line of `TriNumber` is ASKING if `t` is equal to the formula, instead of ASSINGING the value of it to `t`.

Also note that you could just return the expression; you don't really need `t` at all.

Answer (score 0):

I see several issues here:

1. You're using a double-equal sign (`==`) when it looks like you are wanting to assign a value to `t`. You should use a single equal sign (`=`) instead. Or, better yet, simplify the function to:

   ```
   def triNumber(n):
       return (n(n+1))/2  # (sic; see #2)
   ```
2. I don't think that the `(n(n+1))` part of your formula is doing what you would like it to do. I don't know anything about trinumbers, but I'm guessing that you want "n times (n plus 1)"? If so, make sure to use the `*` operator. I think `(n * (n + 1)) / 2` is what you want.  (otherwise, `n(n+1)` means "call the function `n` on `n + 1`," which will fail because you haven't defined a function called `n`.)
3. The first line of your `for` loop, `TriNumber(num)`, isn't actually *doing* anything, from a practical standpoint. It looks like what you're actually trying to do is print a table of trinumber values from 1 to a user-specified number. So, the general structure of your program is going to be a `for` loop containing a `print` statement.
4. Because you're using a `for` loop over a `range` of numbers, you do not need to manually increment `num` each time. Similarly, you do not need to specify `num = 1` before the `for` loop. It's important to note that when you use `range`, the default starting point is 0, not 1. So, if you truly want a range "from 1 to a," then you want `range(1, a)`.
5. Your use of `print` is a little bit wonky in that you're using multiple strings in places where one will do. For example, `print("***""\t""\t""   *****")` should be `print("***\t\t   *****")`.
6. I would take the first two `print` statements out of your `for` loop, since they appear to be a header, so I'm guessing you only want them to print once.
7. Function names generally start with a lowercase letter in Python.
8. In order to print numbers, you have to convert them to strings first, e.g. `str(num)`

Here is how I would revise your code:

```
def triNumber(n):
    return (n * (n + 1)) / 2 #trinumber formula

a = int(input("please input a number")) #user input for number of trinumbers to output

print(" n\t\tTri Number")
print("***\t\t   *****")

for num in range(1, a):
    print(str(num) + "\t\t" + str(triNumber(num)))
```

Hope that helps!

EDIT: A better way to format that last line would be:

```
print("%d\t\t%d" % (num, triNumber(num)))
```

The `%d`s are replaced by the string versions of `num` and `triNumber(num)`, respectively.

Comment: `n(n+1)` is *syntactically* valid, but requires `n` to reference an object which is both callable and can be added to an integer to be *semantically* valid.

Comment: Oh yeah - good point! I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you all for your help,I got it working.  Also thanks for discussing why it works the way it does, I learned a lot from this post

Comment: You're quite welcome. Please consider accepting my answer as correct, and/or upvoting it :)